# Autorelease scope

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I was wondering how the autorelese works on the iPhone. I though that once you send an autorelease to an object **it is guaranteed** to be retained in till the end of the scope of the block the `autorelease` was sent. Is that correct?

I was initializing a view from a NIB in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` like below:

```
    (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    loginViewController = [[[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    [window addSubview: [loginViewController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

and the view did not show at all, all there was on the screen was the `UIWindow`

Now once I removed the `autorelease` from the end of the controller initialization all went smooth from there on.

What is this about?

Cheers,
K.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you call `autorelease`, you give ownership of the object to the current autorelease pool.  The run loop creates a new autorelease pool before it dispatches an event (such as `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`) and destroys that pool when the event finishes.

When you give ownership of your `LoginViewController` to the autorelease pool, it gets released just after the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` returns.  When the view controller deallocates itself, it removes its view from the superview (your window in this case).

Your application delegate should keep ownership of the `LoginViewController` and `release` it in the app delegate's `dealloc` method (or when you're done with your login and have moved on to another view).

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Don's answer, it may be somewhat confusing to say "you give ownership of the object to the current autorelease pool." This might be misunderstood to mean the object is guaranteed to be destroyed when the autorelease pool is drained. This is not correct (though it will happen in this case). Sending `-autorelease` requests that the autorelease pool send a `-release` message when it is drained. If that `-release` message makes retainCount = 0, then the object will be destroyed.

So, in order to do what Don is recommending, you need to create a ivar to keep track of this view controller. His explanation of why the view vanishes is exactly right; but you don't want to just leak the view controller. You want to hold onto it, and release it when you're done with it.

```
@interface ... {
   LoginViewController *_loginViewController;
}

@property (readwrite, retain) LoginViewController *loginViewController;

@implementation ...
@synthesize loginViewController = _loginViewController;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    self.loginViewController = [[[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    [window addSubview: [loginViewController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_loginViewController release]; _loginViewController = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The autoreleasepool is cleaned at the end of the runloop. This means as long as you invoke methods and do stuff, it's still there.

I don't see the error in your code, but the Window is retained properly in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're adding your `LoginViewController` to the autorelease pool it's being released at the end of the run loop. When that happens it also releases its' view and removes it from being displayed.

Comment: The view should be retained by the window. (I don't have access to the documentation though.)

Comment: But when the view controller is deallocated, it removes the view it manages from its superview.